# Can I find the column index of a csv file in discord.py

Tags: python

I am working on a database project, I can currently find the row in which a specific team is located (discord.py) however I would like to find the index of the row and use that to find the players associated with the team. I am using the print function to test that the bot is recieving the correct info before I put it into a message. Below is the code I have for the command.

Apologies if this is simple, I am new to reading/writing csv files in python.

````
import os
import csv
from discord.ext import commands

@bot.command()
async def team(ctx, args):
  with open('Data.csv', 'r') as data:
    csv_file = csv.reader(data)
    query = args.upper()
    for row in csv_file:
      Team = row[0]
      if query == Team:
        print(args)
    else:
      await ctx.send("Sorry I cannot find that team")```
````

Comment: can you provide what's in data.csv?

Comment: `for index, row in enumerate(csv_file):` ?